# Requests from Python request.session() are not recorded in Charles

Tags: python, python-requests, charles-proxy

I'm seeing strange behaviour in Charles proxy when using Python Requests. Both of the following examples result in a successful response (200)

## 1

```
import requests
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)
```

- Successfully recorded in Charles

## 2

```
request = requests.Request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

prepared = request.prepare()
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False

response = session.send(prepared)
```

- Not recorded in Charles

Any idea why Charles does not detect request #2? They are both sent by the same IDE (PyCharm)

Python v3.7 / MacOS Mojave

Answer (score 1):

try set session's proxies, for example:

```
session.verify = False
session.proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888', 'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'}
```